# ConverterConverterSOAP11Port_httpStub cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-axis

I am newbie in implementation of Web Service in Java and tried to follow [Apache Axis 2 tutorials of Eclipse WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html)

but I having some confusion that during importing ConverterClient.java in my project.Step 26 of Eclipse Tutorial shows that six stubs are generated but in my case only two stubs created

1. ConverterCallbackHandler
2. ConverterStub

So my question is that when I am using Axis 2 with Apache Tomcat 7 as runtimes,
Is stub creation process changed instead of using Axis 2 with Apache Tomcat 5 as runtimes ?

Please give me a hint to handle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should not directly add the generated java classes to your project. Instead build and import the .jar into your classpath. Yes for the new version, there is only two files. But there should be no issue with it.